# How to import and use PhotoSwipe with Aurelia / Typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm, aurelia, photoswipe

I am trying to use [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/) in an Aurelia project, but cannot find a way to make it work.

In my aurelio.json under bundles, I have:

```
{
    "name": "photoswipe",
    "path": "../node_modules/photoswipe/dist/",
    "main": "photoswipe.min",
    "resources": [
        "photoswipe-ui-default.min.js",
        "photoswipe.css",
        "default-skin/default-skin.css"
    ]
}
```

in my package.json, I have:

```
"@types/photoswipe": "^4.0.27",
"photoswipe": "^4.1.1"
```

in my .ts module, I have

```
import PhotoSwipe from 'photoswipe';
```

The code I use for opening the gallery (just copied from the [getting started doc](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html))

```
imageClicked() { 

    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    // build items array
    var items = [
        {
            src: 'https://placekitten.com/600/400',
            w: 600,
            h: 400
        },
        {
            src: 'https://placekitten.com/1200/900',
            w: 1200,
            h: 900
        }
    ];

    // define options (if needed)
    var options = {
        // optionName: 'option value'
        // for example:
        index: 0 // start at first slide
    };

    // Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe<PhotoSwipeUI_Default.Options>(pswpElement as HTMLElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
}
```

The aurelia project builds ok, but runtime i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoSwipeUI_Default is not defined
```

I tried adding export to the aurelia.json bundle

```
"exports": [ "PhotoSwipe", "PhotoSwipeUI_Default" ]
```

This didn't change anything.

I tried various import statements:

```
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from 'photoswipe'; // Now PhotoSwipeUI_Default is of type PhotoSwipe
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default' // Module not found compile error
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from 'npm:photoswipe@4.1.1/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js'; // Cannot find module
```

I am in the dark, and my trial and error method of resolving this is going no where.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change up your configuration. You're pointing Aurelia to the minified file which is causing issues apparently. Let the CLI handle minification of the JS files.

```
{
  "name": "photoswipe",
  "path": "../node_modules/photoswipe/dist/",
  "main": "photoswipe",
  "resources": [
    "photoswipe-ui-default.js"
  ]
}
```

You can then import using

```
import PhotoSwipe from 'photoswipe';
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from 'photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default';
```

Also, the photoswipe css files load image files for certain things. A current limitation of the Aurelia CLI is that it breaks this sort of thing. This should be fixed before final release. But for now, you'll need to load the CSS using `link` elements.

```
  <!-- Core CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css">

  <!-- Skin CSS file (styling of UI - buttons, caption, etc.)
     In the folder of skin CSS file there are also:
     - .png and .svg icons sprite, 
     - preloader.gif (for browsers that do not support CSS animations) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/photoswipe/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css">
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and also for preventing my upcoming problem with the css files. I modified the aurelia.json and my imports according to your answer, but I keep getting: "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default'."

Comment: When i get back home I'll try it in TypeScript. I've got it working in ESNext though.

Comment: I'm actually running up against a Rock/Hard place problem as I try to solve the problem. I don't get the error you are getting, though. I get "Error: src\app.ts(36,19): error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature." I can get rid of that error by doing `import * as PhotoSwipe from "photoswipe";`, but that code fails at runtime. It might be best to post another question regarding this issue, as it isn't really an Aurelia question at that point, it's a TypeScript issue.

Comment: This probably has to do with the d.ts file using namespaces which I don't think is recommended any more. (correct me if I'm wrong though)

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I actually get the TS2351 error at compile time when I use `import * as PhotoSwipe from 'photoswipe';`. I will try to modify the .d.ts file and see if I can get it working.

Comment: The fix has to happen in the d.ts file.

Comment: d.ts are only type suggestion - in browser everything should work. Now it works for me with `import * as PhotoSwipe from "photoswipe";
import * as PhotoSwipeUI_Default from "photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.js";`

Comment: Exactly, you have to choose between making the TypeScript compiler happy or the browser runtime happy. I'd typically choose the browser.