# How to incorporate Photoswipe with Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia, photoswipe

I have a really hard time of integrating Photoswipe with Aurelia. I got compile time errors and browser errors.
I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363245/how-to-import-and-use-photoswipe-with-aurelia-typescript/41363893#41363893) and tried what was suggested there (except the change of the typings file, because I don't know what to change), but still it is not working. With the information from the other question I managed to resolve the compile time errors but I still get an error when I initialize Photoswipe:

> Uncaught TypeError: photoswipe_1.default is not a constructor

**aurelia.json:**

```
{
    "name": "photoswipe",
    "main": "photoswipe",
    "path": "../node_modules/photoswipe/dist",
    "resources": [
      "photoswipe-ui-default.js"
    ]
}
```

**package.json:**

I tried it with version 4.0.8 for both the typings and photoswipe, but no change.

```
"@types/photoswipe": "^4.0.27",
"photoswipe": "^4.1.2",
```

**viewmodel:**

I needed to copy the `photoswipe-ui-default.js` to the below folder in my project root, because without `'dist'` it could not be found (o_0)
I find it really strange that it cannot find it by `"photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default.js"` although it is referenced as a resource in aurelia.json.

```
import PhotoSwipe from "photoswipe"; 
import PhotoSwipeUI_Default from "photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.js"
[...]
let pswpElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
let gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, this.items, this.options);
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as PhotoSwipe from "photoswipe"; 
import * as PhotoSwipeUI_Default from "photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.